# Jquery UI Tabs add class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Below is my HTML set up for the tabs which all works fine, i want to extend it a bit by changing the class of the outer containing div (id=tab-wrap class=bike) to whatever tab is showing. The idea is to change the background image based on the tab.

```
    <div id="tab-wrap" class="bike">

        <div id="batter-finder">
            <h1>Battery Finder</h1>
            <p>Choose Your Application then find your battery</p>

            <div id="tabs">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#bike">Bike</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#atv">ATV</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#utv">UTV</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#snow">Snow</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#water">Water</a></li>
               </ul>

               <div id="bike">
                  <p>Bike content</p>
               </div>

               <div id="atv">
                  <p>ATV content</p>
               </div>

               <div id="utv">
                  <p>UTV content</p>
               </div>

               <div id="snow">
                  <p>Snow content</p>
               </div>

               <div id="water">
                  <p>Water content</p>
               </div>

            </div> <!-- /tabs -->

        </div>

    </div>
```

So if i select the tab "water" i'd like to change the class from:

```
<div id="tab-wrap" class="bike">
```

to

```
<div id="tab-wrap" class="water">
```

An elegant fade in/out change would be good. My jquery is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } });
});
```

Appreciate the help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this,

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e93JK/)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
    fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' },
    select: function(event, ui) {
         $("#tab-wrap").attr('class', ui.panel.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    $("#tab-wrap").attr('class', $(ui.panel).attr('id'));
}
```

or if you want to bind the event when you declare the tabs:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#tab-wrap").attr('class', $(ui.panel).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Check out the events section of the [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs) demo page.