# Jquery ui tabs add css class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Help me to check buttons css class inside UI Tabs and add another one.
I have some buttons.
All buttons placed inside UI one tab.

I want to add another one class "red" if span.jrIconStar.

```
<button class="Button" data-states='{"on":"jrIconStar","off":"jrIconEmptyStar"}'>

  <span title="Main Photo" class="jrIconStar"></span>

</button>                                                             
<button class="Button" data-states='{"on":"jrIconStar","off":"jrIconEmptyStar"}'>

  <span title="Photo" class="jrIconEmptyStar"></span>

</button>
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuiM8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI Tabs add class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271235/jquery-ui-tabs-add-class)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a given class to your span with id `jrIconStar`. To achieve this use the following jQuery code:

`jQuery("#jrIconStar").addClass("className")` or
`$("#jrIconStar").addClass("className")`
If you want this to happen on a button click then you can use it in the following way:

`$("body").on("click", "#yourButtonId", function(){
   $("#jrIconStar").addClass("className"); 
});`

If this is not the case please provide us with more information! Hope this helps you out!

**EDIT:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271277/7654934

I believe this is the answer that you are looking for.

Comment: this code not working in my case, as i sad this buttons inside jQuery UI Tabs. But i don't understand how to (

Comment: If you provide me with a jsFiddle of your issue I will take a look and try to help you out!

Comment: Not quite that. my buttons inside one tab, i don't need to switch between tabs.

Comment: Just use the logic to change your class?

Comment: can i speak Russian here ?

Comment: i think i don't need .on("click" function. i need to check if . If .jrIconStar add new class

Comment: Buddy try to be more clear, in the question you ask how to add a new class to an element now you ask how to check if the element already has the class? please be more specific otherwise I cannot help you